Liability for delayed package that buyer no longer wants
Act 1:
Alice runs a small online store in the UK. Bob (US) makes a purchase that Alice forgets to ship. About two months later, Alice is notified that Bob has filed a charge dispute. (Meanwhile, Bob's credit card provided has reversed the charge.) Is it legal for Alice to ship the item in response to being notified of the dispute?
Act 2:
Alice ships the item, resulting in the charge being reinstated on Bob's credit card. However, Bob (prior to being aware of the reinstatement) refuses shipment. Later, on learning that the charge was reinstated, Bob contacts Alice demanding a refund. Is Alice obligated to offer one, or can she keep both their money and the item?
Throughout this fiasco, Bob has attempted to communicate with Alice but received no response.

You didn't fix it.  Have they been issued a refund or not?  Oh... and now we find out in a comment elsewhere that you are actually the buyer?!  So did you get a refund or not?  (If I had more DVs for creating unnecessary confusion I would use them...)

I don't care what their names are, my point is that you are being unclear and a bit weird in framing the issue.  (Case in point: "Act 1 & 2")  That Alice owes Bob something, either a refund or the product, should be obvious.

@MichaelHall, both Alice and my CCP seem to disagree.

What does the Chinese Communist Party have to do with this?  Anyway, it sounds like you have a dispute on your hands...  Good luck!

@MichaelHall, Credit Card Provider.

I wasn't a close-voter but I suspect the reason it was closed is because the original (pre-edited) version was asking for legal advice, and your comments (about your credit card provider, and, in a now deleted comment, stating that you were the buyer in this scenario) make it clear that this is still really a request for legal advice disguised as something else.

Maybe you'll manage to get it re-opened now that it's been edited but on the other hand it still suffers from the problem of asking multiple questions in one post. Plus the first question doesn't really make much sense: "is it legal for Alice to ship the item?" - what possible reason could there be for this to be illegal? As a general rule anyone can post anything they want to anyone as long as the item itself isn't illegal in some way.

@JBentley, because Alice is already in breach of contract at that point, and Bob's payment has already been rescinded. In Bob's mind, the transaction has been cancelled. By sending the item, Alice is at that point forcing Bob to make a purchase against Bob's wishes. And AFAICT, UK law recognizes this; the answer to the first question is in fact "no, it is not legal" (see the accepted Answer).

@Matthew No, by sending the item, Alice is giving the item to Bob. In "Act 1" Bob has had the transaction reversed, so he has the money and isn't forced to purchase anything merely because Alice sent it to him. Maybe your question is really "Is it legal for Alice to ship the item and to reinstate the charge?"

"Alice is at that point forcing Bob to make a purchase against Bob's wishes."  That's your personal interpretation of Alice's motives.  Because she isn't "forcing" anything - she realizes she made a mistake when she sees the charged reversed, and could very well be acting in good faith to close the deal and provide Bob a remedy.  Because Bob never cancelled the order or told her he didn't want the item any more...

@MichaelHall, Alice is ignoring Bob's attempts to communicate. Alice is also certainly aware that the delivery was refused, Alice has made no attempt, at any point, to contact Bob, and Alice is not responding to Bob's request for a refund. Also, I repeat: per UK law, IIUC, Alice, due to the delay, is required to contact Bob before shipping the item. There are many, many indicators that Alice is not acting in good faith.

Sounds like you have answered the original question then.  Again, good luck.

See https://www.gov.uk/online-and-distance-selling-for-businesses (UK distance selling). Amongst other things, Bob has the right to  return the goods for one or two weeks at your expense.
It should have been obvious to Alice that after not delivering the goods for two months, Bob has absolutely zero interest in the goods anymore, and return the goods after 0 days instead of the required 7 or 14 days. And Bob absolutely has the right to do so.
If Alice tries to keep Bob's money, I'll predict a small claims court will give Alice a telling off, and it will become more expensive for Alice.

Is stating "any returns not faulty or damaged will be paid for by the customer" sufficient to avoid any liability? What if the purchase was multiple items each individually less than £42?

@Matthew, No. The law states that the customer has the right to cancel the transaction (and return the goods) within 14 days. That cannot be weakened in the terms of your shop. Regarding the limit of £42, I have not looked up the actual law text, but I expect it is on the complete transaction and not the price of individual items.

What does your contract say?
You have a contract. It has terms. Do those terms deal with cancellation? Are those terms legal in both your jurisdiction and the jurisdiction of the buyer? If so, did the buyer cancel the contract in accordance with those terms?
If it doesn’t, then there will be an implied term that you must fulfil your obligations within a reasonable time. If you don’t, you are in breach of contract and gives the buyer the right to damages and may entitle them to terminate the contract as well.
Is two months a reasonable time to delay shipping? It depends on the item - for a new car, or a custom manufactured part for an oil rig, it probably is, for standard consumer products, it probably isn’t. Especially since the reason you didn’t ship is that you forgot - and that’s not reasonable.
So either you have a contract, which means you get the money and they get the item. Or, you no longer have a contract which means you get the item and they get the money. There is no scenario in which you get both.
